# Cannot deploy SSRS reports on server, but can remotely

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2

This is strange. I can deploy remotely from other machines, such as my developer workstation. However, logged in to the server running SSRS itself, as the same user as on my development machine, I am unable to deploy reports -- with the error message being "Error rsAccessDenied : The permissions granted to user 'XXX\YYY' are insufficient for performing this operation". Moreover, if I go to the report server webpage (in either IE or Firefox, results are the same either way), I am not able to change or view security settings, again, despite being logged in as the same user. I can do this on my dev workstation no problem.

My permissions are system user and system administrator, and I have content manager permissions in the SSRS folder.

Googling for an answer is very difficult because everyone is talking about either not being able to deploy at all locally (because it's their first time and they haven't set up SSRS fully), or being able to deploy locally but not remotely. Neither of those are my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to how Windows strips administrator rights for domain users on the machine itself. My domain user belongs to the BUILTIN\Administrators group, through which it was able to have deployment rights via the SSRS permissions granted to that group. When logged into the server directly via remote desktop, Windows strips the administrator credentials (but silently, of course). I've run into this before. There are two solutions:

- Give the domain user permissions directly in SSRS.
- Create a new local or domain group for administrators and assign users to that group, then give them permissions via SSRS.